# forked 3 times trying to consistently output a value incremented in a loop

Tags: c, process, synchronization, semaphore, pid

Goal is to have output to start from 1 and get to 150 at the moment its only 1 to 60 with multiple duplicates. Id like to leave main the same and only mess with the process() function using semaphores. This is my interpretation of how to use post and wait. If this is wrong please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
// //dev/shm/sem.X <- unlinks
sem_t *sem;
/*
    sem = sem_open("X",O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, N);
    sem_unlink("X");
    sem_getvalue(sem,&N);
    sem_post(sem);
*/
void process(){
    int ret;
    int N = 1;
    int a;
    sem = sem_open("X",O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, 1);
    sem_unlink("X");
    
    for(int i = 0; i< 50; i++){
        sem_wait(sem);
        FILE* infile = fopen ("infile.txt", "r");
        fscanf (infile, "%d", &N); 
        fclose (infile);
        N++;
        printf("N: %d Process ID: %d \n",N,getpid());
        infile = fopen("infile.txt", "w");
        fprintf(infile,"%d",N);
        fclose(infile);
        sem_post(sem);
    }
    
    exit(0);
}
int main(){
    
    FILE *fp = fopen("infile.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp,"%d", 1);
    fclose(fp);
    
    int pid, pid1, pid2;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        //child1, Last
        printf("Starting Process C: \n");
        process();
    }
    else{
        pid1 = fork();
        if(pid1 == 0){
            //child2, Middle
            printf("Starting Process B: \n");
            process();
        }
        else{
            pid2 = fork();
            if(pid2 == 0){
                //child 3, First
                printf("Starting Process A: \n");
                process();
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        
    }
    //sem_close(&X);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you create the semaphore file in the parent process and remove it after all children has died? Right now it seems likely that _all_ children will succeed in creating it since you remove it directly after creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `sem_open` in `process` followed by `sem_unlink` is incorrect.

Each process will get a *different* semaphore so they will *not* coordinate.

Move the `sem_open` to `main` and remove the `sem_unlink`. Then, all processes will use the same/correct semaphore.

Note that the main/master process doesn't do a `wait` [and terminates immediately], so the subprocesses attach to the init process. Better to do: `while (wait(NULL) >= 0);` at the bottom of `main`

We need to do `sem_close` and then `sem_unlink` at the bottom of `main`

---

Here's some refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// //dev/shm/sem.X <- unlinks
sem_t *sem;

#if 0
sem = sem_open("X", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, N);
sem_unlink("X");
sem_getvalue(sem, &N);
sem_post(sem);
#endif

void
process()
{
    int ret;
    int N = 1;
    int a;

// NOTE/BUG: by doing this here each process gets it's own semaphore so nothing
// will be coordinated
#if 0
    sem = sem_open("X", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, 1);
    sem_unlink("X");
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        sem_wait(sem);
        FILE *infile = fopen("infile.txt", "r");

        fscanf(infile, "%d", &N);
        fclose(infile);
        N++;
        printf("N: %d Process ID: %d \n", N, getpid());
        infile = fopen("infile.txt", "w");
        fprintf(infile, "%d", N);
        fclose(infile);
        sem_post(sem);
    }

    exit(0);
}

int
main()
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("infile.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%d", 1);
    fclose(fp);

// NOTE/FIX: one semaphore for all processes
#if 1
    sem = sem_open("X", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, 1);
    //sem_unlink("X");
#endif

    int pid, pid1, pid2;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child1, Last
        printf("Starting Process C: \n");
        process();
    }
    else {
        pid1 = fork();
        if (pid1 == 0) {
            // child2, Middle
            printf("Starting Process B: \n");
            process();
        }
        else {
            pid2 = fork();
            if (pid2 == 0) {
                // child 3, First
                printf("Starting Process A: \n");
                process();
            }
            else {

            }
        }

    }
    // sem_close(&X);

// NOTE/FIX: wait for all subprocesses to finish
#if 1
    while (1) {
        pid = wait(NULL);
        if (pid < 0)
            break;
    }
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: we must close and unlink so that we can be invoked again
#if 1
    sem_close(sem);
    sem_unlink("X");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

The above works but I'd use a loop to start the three processes rather than nested `if/else` statements. This solution would be more obvious if we had to create a 1000 processes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// //dev/shm/sem.X <- unlinks
sem_t *sem;

#if 0
sem = sem_open("X", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, N);
sem_unlink("X");
sem_getvalue(sem, &N);
sem_post(sem);
#endif

void
process()
{
    int ret;
    int N = 1;
    int a;

// NOTE/BUG: by doing this here each process gets it's own semaphore so nothing
// will be coordinated
#if 0
    sem = sem_open("X", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, 1);
    sem_unlink("X");
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        sem_wait(sem);
        FILE *infile = fopen("infile.txt", "r");

        fscanf(infile, "%d", &N);
        fclose(infile);
        N++;
        printf("N: %d Process ID: %d \n", N, getpid());
        infile = fopen("infile.txt", "w");
        fprintf(infile, "%d", N);
        fclose(infile);
        sem_post(sem);
    }

    exit(0);
}

int
main()
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("infile.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%d", 1);
    fclose(fp);

// NOTE/FIX: one semaphore for all processes
#if 1
    sem = sem_open("X", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777, 1);
    //sem_unlink("X");
#endif

    pid_t pid;

    for (int count = 1;  count <= 3;  ++count) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
            process();
    }

// NOTE/FIX: wait for all subprocesses to finish
#if 1
    while (1) {
        pid = wait(NULL);
        if (pid < 0)
            break;
    }
#endif

// NOTE/FIX: we must close and unlink so that we can be invoked again
#if 1
    sem_close(sem);
    sem_unlink("X");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```